# How to define routes that include a dynamic organization name in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, saas

I'm building a Rails 5.2 SaaS application that allows users to belong to many "organizations".  Users will only see content for their currently active organization.

I started down the path of using subdomains, but after a little more research have [decided to avoid them for now](https://blog.clubhouse.io/building-a-saas-app-you-should-probably-stick-to-a-single-subdomain-455695e1d03c).

My new approach (to make it explicit to the user what organization they are using, support sharing links, browser history etc..) is to embed the organization name in the path.  For example:

```
https://app.example.com/foo/posts   # Posts for org "foo"
https://app.example.com/foo/posts/7 # Post for org "foo"
https://app.example.com/bar/posts   # Posts for org "bar"
https://app.example.com/settings    # General account settings
https://app.example.com/signin      # Sign in
```

My problem is how to do this with Rails routes?  I've tried to use a dynamic scope:

```
scope ':org' do
  resources :posts
end
```

Results in errors like:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts", :org=>#<Organization id: 1, name: "My Organization", ...}, missing required keys: [:id]
```

For the code:

```
# layouts/application.html.erb
<%= link_to post, post, class: 'dropdown-item' %>
```

Any suggestions on how to configure routes to support this use case?

Comment: Does each org have_many :posts?

Comment: Yes, I clarified a bit in in the question, but each organization has many posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the resources macro:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts, except: [:new, :create]
  resources :organizations, path: '/', only: [] do
    resources :posts, module: :organizations, only: [:new, :index, :create]
  end
end
```

`$ rails routes:`

```
               Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                           Controller#Action
                posts GET    /posts(.:format)                      posts#index
            edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)             posts#edit
                 post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                  posts#show
                      PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)                  posts#update
                      PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                  posts#update
                      DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                  posts#destroy
   organization_posts GET    /:organization_id/posts(.:format)     organizations/posts#index
                      POST   /:organization_id/posts(.:format)     organizations/posts#create
new_organization_post GET    /:organization_id/posts/new(.:format) organizations/posts#new
```

By using the `module:` option you can setup a separate controller for the nested context:

```
# app/controllers/organizations/posts_controller.rb
class Organizations::PostsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_organization!

  # Index for posts belonging to a specific organization
  # GET    /:organization_id/posts
  def index
    @posts = @organization.posts
  end

  # GET    /:organization_id/posts/new
  def new
    @post = @organization.posts.new
  end

  # POST   /:organization_id/posts
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
    def set_organization!
      @organization = Organization.includes(:posts)
                                  .find_by!(name: params[:organization_id])
    end 

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title)
    end
end
```

---

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # Index for posts belonging to all organizations
  # GET /posts
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  def show
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  def update
    if @post.update(post_params)
      redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.'
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title)
    end
end
```

However you should be beware when creating routes that start with a dynamic segment - routes have priority in the order that they are defined and a route that starts with a dynamic segment will be "greedy" and swallow other routes if they are not defined first.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks @max! This is exactly what I was looking for. Now the question is whether or not the benefits outweigh the "clunkiness" in the code base (i.e. paths get quite verbose for nested resources, I need to worry about passing the organization to every path etc..).

Comment: You should generally avoid nesting more than one level and only really nest the routes when the nesting provides context.